# How to sort a sequence in Nim?

Tags: sorting, list-comprehension, nim-lang

I have a sequence generated by list comprehension as follows:

```
var a_bigram_list = lc[a[i..i+2] | (i <- 0..<len(a)), string]
```

Now, I would like to sort it but `sort(a_bigram_list)` will result in the following compilation error

```
Error: type mismatch: got (seq[string])
but expected one of: 
proc sort[A, B](t: OrderedTableRef[A, B]; cmp: proc (x, y: (A, B)): int)
proc sort[A, B](t: var OrderedTable[A, B]; cmp: proc (x, y: (A, B)): int)
proc sort[A](t: CountTableRef[A])
proc sort[A](t: var CountTable[A])
proc sort[T](a: var openArray[T]; cmp: proc (x, y: T): int; order = SortOrder.Ascending)
```

Is there any way of sorting a sequence? Or do I need to convert it to array? If so, can is there a way to obtain an array from lc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sort` works with sequences (`openArray` is a generic parameter type that accepts both `array`s and `seq`s), but it expects a comparison proc as a second parameter.

You can provide it a default cmp from system module:

```
sort(a_bigram_list, system.cmp)
```

Comment: How an own, local implementation of the compare method would look like?

Comment: A custom sort example: https://nim-lang.org/docs/algorithm.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 4):

As of [October 2018](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/9174), your intended code `sort(a_bigram_list)` will now work just fine, since `sort[T](...)` now uses `system.cmp[T]` as the implied sort function if you only provide one argument.